# DB2 SELECT EXCEPT with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, select, except, db2-zos

I'm trying to compare two tables in a DB2 database in z/OS using SPUFI to submit SQL queries.

I'm doing this by using `EXCEPT` to see the difference between two `SELECT` queries.

I need to filter the `SELECT` statement from the first query with a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT KEY_FIELD_1,LOOKUP_FIELD_1  
FROM TABLE_1  
WHERE FILTER_FIELD = '1'  
EXCEPT  
SELECT KEY FIELD_2,LOOKUP_FIELD_2  
FROM TABLE_2
```

I got results back, but it also returned an error `-199` Is this because the `WHERE` clause is not present in the second `SELECT` statement?

```
ERROR: ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD EXCEPT.  
TOKEN <ERR_STMT> <WNG_STMT> GET SQL  
SAVEPOINT HOLD FREE ASSOCIATE WAS EXPECTED
```

Comment: no..it isn't because of the `where` missing from the second query. it would help if you show the `where` condition.

Comment: apologies, that wasn't very clear - have provided the exact `WHERE` statement and also added the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try introducing parentheses e.g.

```
( SELECT KEY_FIELD_1,LOOKUP_FIELD_1  
FROM TABLE_1  
WHERE FILTER_FIELD = '1' )  
EXCEPT  
( SELECT KEY FIELD_2,LOOKUP_FIELD_2  
FROM TABLE_2 )
```